# How to merge small files in SparkSQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a Spark application using SparkSQL. How do I merge small files? I know about `.repartition` and `.coalesce` but this can't be done using SparkSQL.

Comment: `spark.sql` returns a dataframe, which can indeed be coalesced and repartitioned before written to a different location

Comment: How would I do this if the sql inside is a CTAS? `spark.sql("create table as select....")`

Comment: What size files is that making currently? How many files?

Comment: 1-5MB files and it is generating 20000 files

Comment: I think the general recommendation would be to use `spark.sql`, get a dataframe, then `df.write` after a coalesce, to output some Parquet (or ORC) data, then run `create external table` with the location you wrote to

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm doing. I was just curious how to do it directly using spark.sql

Comment: I don't really know. There is a whole bunch of `hive.merge.*` properties. Have you tried them as per what the other question shows? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties

Comment: df.write is part of Spark SQL uiatm.

Comment: If you need to do this incrementally, then you need to consider that as well. You get to point that imo only the newer data needs to merged, not all the old data as well. I think cricket_007 alludes to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpts from [DeepSense](https://deepsense.ai/optimize-spark-with-distribute-by-and-cluster-by/) engineering blog (2016)

> ***Distribute by*** and ***cluster by*** clauses are really cool features in SparkSQL. Unfortunately, this subject remains relatively
>   unknown to most users
> ...
>
> `SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 2`
>   `SELECT * FROM df DISTRIBUTE BY key`
>
> Equivalent in DataFrame API:
>  `df.repartition($"key", 2)`
>
> ...

Caveat: I cannot testify that it works as advertised; it looked very promising when I found that blog, but it has stayed on my to-do list ever since    `:-/`